# How to substract 2 sub groups sum in rdlc report

Tags: asp.net, report, rdlc, reportviewer, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am using `rdlc` report to display a report.

In that I am using Groups and Sub groups; I want to substract the sub groups sum and display it in another text box.

How to do it.

In the image :

- Sub group 'Expenses' sum is 86
- Sub group  'Income' sum is 400

I want to do 86-400.

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhrW2.png)

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I have a very limited knowledge in rdlc reports, can i solve this with any expression